# average of corresponding cells for sectioning

Tags: excel, average

I have an excel workbook with paired data sets of the type [columnA=distance:columnB=data] There are thousands of data points.

What I'm looking to do is this: I have a sectioning for column A . I want to find the average of corresponding cells in the data column (column B) for the sectioning.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Average of a filter of multiple columns in Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11826376/average-of-a-filter-of-multiple-columns-in-excel)

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of simple options:

- [autofilter](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/quick-start-filter-data-by-using-an-autofilter-HA010370616.aspx)

  - filter on column A, then highlight column B and have a look at average value in the bottom right corner in the excel status bar
  - or create a formula [`=SUBTOTAL(1, B:B)`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/subtotal-function-HP010062463.aspx) somewhere in your sheet which ignores hidden cells and works well with autofilter
- [excel table](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/overview-of-excel-tables-HA010048546.aspx)

  - same as autofilter, but it comes with built-in TOTAL row feature that you can set up to display the average
- [`=AVERAGEIFS()`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/averageifs-function-HA010047493.aspx) or similar formula - see e.g.:

  - [Average of a filter of multiple columns in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11826376/1176601),
  - [Calculating average of specific values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19299160/1176601)